# How do you exclude conf folder in sbt dist task

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to create a package using sbt-native-packager without the conf folder being in the project jar.  I have my conf folder included as such:

`resourceDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory(_ => new File("conf"))`

This include the conf files in the project jar is there a way I can have the conf files included on the classpath for runtime,test,console but not dist?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue. Alexey's answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filterNot { case (_, name) =>
  Seq("application.conf", "anotherconfig").contains(name)
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of your @Alexey Yamshanov very useful above answer.

It excludes some configuration files from packaging inclusion.
For instance ending with `dev.conf`, `prod.conf`

```
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= {
  _.filterNot { case (_, name) => Seq("dev.conf", "prod.conf").exists(name.endsWith) }
}
```